# How do I combine 'this' with a first-child selector?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to combine 'this' with div:first-child to get the html value of a hidden div that makes up the body of an anchor tag.  How should this work?

```
$('a').click( function(){
  $(this + "div:first-child").html();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$('a').click( function(){
  $("div:first-child", this).html();
}
```

It selects the html of the `"div:first-child"` inside of the link

Answer (score 3):

It's worth pointing out, first, that a `div` is a block-level element, and as such is invalid within an inline-element (such as an `a`). That said, it might be worth amending your selector:

```
$('a').click( function(){
  $(this).find("div:first-child").html();
}
```

Or:

```
$('a').click( function(){
  $(this).find("div:hidden").html();
}
```

I've not changed your elements from `div` to `span`, though I strongly suggest that you should. Incidentally, using context-selectors (`$('div:first-child',this)`) calls `find()` internally anyway, converting it to: `$(this).find('div:first-child')`.

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`:hidden`-selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/).
- [jQuery's context-selector](http://api.jquery.com/jquery#selector-context).

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks for the lesson.  I'll change them to spans.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(this).children("div:first-child").html();
```

To access child elements within the anchor-link element.

Comment: @Tom how do you know its a `child element`?

Comment: Good point, assumed it would be, you solution is more elegant.

Comment: @Tom you know what happens when you assume?

Comment: "Assumption is the mother of all cock-ups"

Comment: @Tom hmmmm no -- assume means you make an *a$s* out of *u* and *me*

Comment: I fail to see why it implicates you, yeah I get things wrong, but you presented a much better solution with which I agreed. What's your problem? Do you want me to delete the answer?

Comment: The "out of u and me" is just a play on the spelling of "assume". It's an old saying. Don't think he was intentionaly trying to ride you about it.

Comment: @scrappedcola yeah I got that, I just don't see the point in attacking someone who made a simple mistake when the site is about helping people.

Comment: @Tom im not attacking. its about learning. and i am teaching how to not assume ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click( function(){
  $("div:first-child", this).html();
}
```